# How to safely confirm a password by entering it twice in a bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to create a bash script where a user can choose a username, a password and confirm the password by entering it twice. If the passwords do not match the user should be prompted to enter it again. If the passwords match, the script should create a passwordhash, otherwise ask again until it is correct.

So far I have the code below but I am not sure if this is the right way to do this.
Is there a problem with the following bash script?

```
# read username
read -p "Username: " username

# read password twice
read -s -p "Password: " password
echo 
read -s -p "Password (again): " password2

# check if passwords match and if not ask again
while [ "$password" != "$password2" ];
do
    echo 
    echo "Please try again"
    read -s -p "Password: " password
    echo
    read -s -p "Password (again): " password2
done

# create passwordhash
passwordhash=`openssl passwd -1 $password`

# do something with the user and passwordhash
```

Comment: The problem with the script is that you don't understand how it works.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you for the comment but this does not help me very much. I wrote the script myself and therefore I do know what it does, but since I am not so familiar with bash I am not sure if for example the password entered gets logged in a history or even worse.

Comment: In your question you wrote "`I found a solution which works fine, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do this.`" Having just that info my comment makes sense. Seems like a misunderstanding. I have edited this and spent you an upvote..

Comment: Btw, I would disable terminal output when entering the password. Check [this](http://egloo.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/turn-off-echo-in-a-terminal/)

Comment: @hek2mgl sorry for the misunderstanding, I should have chosen better words. Thank you for the tip with the terminal output, I now use `stty -echo` before and `stty echo` after the password input.

Comment: The answer of @klashxx together with the `stty` stuff looks like a good solution. However, I would overwrite `$password` with it's hash immediately to get the clear text password out of memory as soon as possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A way to reduce verbosity:

```
#!/bin/bash
   
read -p "Username: " username
while true; do
  read -s -p "Password: " password
  echo
  read -s -p "Password (again): " password2
  echo
  [ "$password" = "$password2" ] && break
  echo "Please try again"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that too but the problem there is that if the passwords match the "Please try again" message is still echoed.

Comment: @Passuf you can use `||` to trigger the echo statement when the if condition is false: `[ "$password" = "$password2" ] && break || echo "Please try again"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget a *continue*, so the while loop will start over on two different passwords.

```
while [ -z "$password" ]; do
  echo "Please enter a password: "
  read -s first
  read -s -p "Retype a password: " second
  if [ $first == $second ];
  then
    password=$first
    echo "Both passwords are the same. Continuing.."
  else
    echo "You have entered different passwords. Try again.."
    continue
  fi
  break
done
```